# Xcode: Method definition not found message on a non-existing method (?) + slight color change in XIB

Tags: xcode, xib

I have two basic practical problems:

1) The first one is really stupid. I receive a message saying: "Method definition for 'aIncreasedSelection' not found, together with an "Incomplete Implementation". 
Well, that is quite strange, because I don't have this method in neither my .m or .h file (and the class name is mentioned in the remark). 
I *used to* implement this method, but I deleted it because it was redundant. In a certain way, it appears as if my Xcode project can't let go of the method...

2) The second question is also a very mysterious one. I have a couple of viewControllers in which I have put the identical same background, and the identical same buttons. It's really identical in size and position in the screen as well (I defined the pixels). For an unknown reason, when I switch between the views, one of the buttons changes very slightly its color (it is a Photoshop created button with mirror effect on the bottom, it's the mirror that becomes *lighter*). That is really annoying because it's supposed to be identical; when the user switches views now, he can see that there is a color difference in the button (supposed to be planted as a button in a dock, which should be identical over the entire app)...

Very frustrating as I cannot solve these small mistakes... Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Btw, sorry that I forgot to mention 'hi all' and if my question on the second topic wasn't too clear...

Comment: First error looks like a typo... Try a find for 'aIncreasedSelection' on your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I used find selections on "Increased" and all kinds of variations, but it's just not there :-/ ...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first problem, if you have verified that it no longer exists in your .h or .m file, try to cmd+shift+k and clean your project, then rebuild. This should update everything and in theory solve that issue for you.

As for the second problem, it sounds strange indeed. Is there any chance you could provide pictures somehow? Are you statically loading the image into similar buttons, or are you doing something differently?

Comment: I tried it out, but the result was negative... Can I send my project to you by mail so you can have a look by yourself? It is currently still small because it's the first I do this :-) So I will certainly not ask you to start debugging, it won't take anything from your time...! Greetings Kim

Comment: By the way, indeed, I just imported buttons in the project and used IB to populate the buttons. Afterwards I did animate some buttons, but not the button I'm having trouble with...

Comment: Well, I mean I imported the images to put on the button :-D

Comment: I would be happy to take a look, though I will not be able to do so for a few hours. If you could post it to a file storage site and post the download link so others could see that would be the best I think. MegaUpload or something along those lines.

Comment: I shared my files on: http://www.4shared.com/folder/0OM6gaga/_online.html   ... it's a lot of files, I don't know if there is any way to do this.I was also unable to import the .proj file on the Share. I hope I didn't forget any file by mistake! If you import it, I hope you will get the same bugs as I have in my project, I don't think it's normal! First point appears in the targetViewController.m; Then, you need to click on the button "Notify me" from the main menu and look at the shadow below the button "Report". I hope it works out... well, I've been asking quite a lot already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Re - opening my project solved my first problem (unlike the refresh - cmd + shift + k, which didn't work). The color problem is not solved despite :-/ 
It was definitely a bug since I didn't change anything. It is in fact - very confusing!